# ios6 facebook intergration - ios/xcode

Tags: xcode, facebook, sdk, ios6

Probably a silly question and please dont judge me. Just want to be sure. But are the facebook tutorials on developers.facecook.com still count on the new ios6? Can I still follow them to implement facebook on an app running ios6? thank you in advance..

Answer (score 3):

Facebook SDK 3.1 comes with iOS6 support and native UI views.
It works fine.

Regards,
Vince

Answer (score 1):

As of my knowledge they are working on a better implementation of iOS6 with their 3.0 SDK. But I've implemented the 3.0 SDK of Facebook and it works great.

Comment: This is an old answer and Vincents answer currently holds as true.